# iPhone - Core Data crash on migration

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have problems, when i install app from Xcode all works but if I build app and install it from iTunes I have an error with the database at launch. 
This happens only than i have changes in the core data model and need to migrate to a new version.
At first launch at crashes with message:

```
Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00034588 pwrite + 20
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000505ec _sqlite3_purgeEligiblePagerCacheMemory + 2808
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000243d8 sqlite3_backup_init + 7712
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000244ac sqlite3_backup_init + 7924
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000d418 sqlite3_file_control + 4028
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000228b4 sqlite3_backup_init + 764
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00022dd0 sqlite3_backup_init + 2072
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000249a8 sqlite3_backup_init + 9200
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00029800 sqlite3_open16 + 11360
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0002a200 sqlite3_open16 + 13920
10  libsqlite3.dylib                0x0002ab84 sqlite3_open16 + 16356
11  libsqlite3.dylib                0x00049418 sqlite3_prepare16 + 54056
12  libsqlite3.dylib                0x00002940 sqlite3_step + 44
13  CoreData                        0x00011958 _execute + 44
14  CoreData                        0x000113e0 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 696
15  CoreData                        0x000994be -[NSSQLConnection prepareAndExecuteSQLStatement:] + 26
16  CoreData                        0x000be14c -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:] + 244
17  CoreData                        0x000b6c60 -[NSSQLiteInPlaceMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 1040
18  CoreData                        0x000aceb0 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) migrateStoreAtURL:toURL:storeType:options:withManager:error:] + 92
19  CoreData                        0x000ad6f0 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy migrateStoreAtURL:withManager:metadata:options:error:] + 72
20  CoreData                        0x000ac9ee -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 880
21  CoreData                        0x0000965c -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 1328
```

At next launches app doesn't loads data from database.

Comment: Is this the 500,000+ record database you asked about <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848901/iphone-hard-computation-and-caching">in this previous question?</a>

Comment: yes, but this version store only 34000 :)

Comment: I have this error only then i have new version of coredata model, that add new field to entity. if i user prevision model all work.

Comment: Sorry about the tags. It's habit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Some of my beta testers are getting this error. I have since moved away from Core Data but would love to know what is going on for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying your database.sqlite file from the Resources folder to the apps Documents folder? You should do that on the apps first launch (and after that, check that there's a file in place so you don't overwrite it).

Comment: I try to do it

NSString *path = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
 path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName];
 path = [path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
    
 NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
  NSString *pathResource = (NSString*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kDatabaseName ofType:@"sqlite"];
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathResource toPath:path error:nil];
 }
But also have error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a "crash" and not a `xxx failed to launch in time` error? Migration often takes several seconds, and it could be longer than the amount of time Apple gives you for initialization. You may have to migrate in the background.

Comment: Also see this post which describes lightweight migration, which takes a lot less time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone