# Data migration with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a lite app on store which uses core data for data persistence, it would be nice if users could migrate their data to the full version of the app after upgrading.

I found [this](http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/) article but it talks only about SQLite databases.

I seem not to find any information about this no where.

Anyone an idea on how to do this ?

Comment: I found this post in the following link the best for core data migration ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no difference between SQLite and Core Data in this regard. Just copy the file you use as Core Data store as described in the article you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Data migration is covered in detail in the Apple document
["Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)

Best wishes,
xj