# Simplest way to update Entities in Data Core without losing data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an iOS app on App Store that utilized Data Core with SQLite engine.  The updated version that I plan to update needed to add several more attributes (fields) to an entity (table).  What is the simplest way to handle this without losing data on already existing SQLite database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is with what's called a "Core Data Migration".

Here's the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Also, some initial posts:

[Data migration with core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980804/data-migration-with-core-data)

[core data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347146/core-data-migration)

http://www.timisted.net/blog/archive/core-data-migration/