# Steps for migrating a core database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementation of “Automatic Lightweight Migration” for Core Data (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone)

I submitted an update of my app in the appstore. In this update I've added some things in my core database. Now I get some complaints that the app is crashing all the time. After some searching I found that I needed to migrate my core database. My question is now what are the steps I need to do this. I've read the documentation on the developer website but can't get it working.

I'm using the latest xcode. Any help?

Comment: really useful guys that are downvoting without a comment...  It would be useful if you tell us what exactely is the problem (crashlog), what have you tried. Please give more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make migrations if you are renaming any fields, but if you just added a few fields, you just need to put in version number on your core data file and core data takes care of everything.

Here is more information : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

This isn't as hard to do as it sounds. The hardest part is actually doing the tests yourself, as you need two databases, but remember, you can go back as well in Xcode.