# Issue with data migration in sqlite database (coredata)

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data-migration

firstly i'wer having two entities in my `.xcdatamodeld`, `GameInfo` and `Score` with values stored in sqlite db.

now, i had to made change in my GameInfo entity, one new field added to it. so in my new .xcdatamodeld Gameinfo entity has one more field then old one.

is there any way to get values from my old sqlite to new one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement database migration.

I'd look in to automatic lightweight migration - check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312137/1103584).