# Just a small clarification on Core Data Lightweight Migration before 1st app release

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm (hopefully) close to releasing my first app which uses Core Data. Now I've read all of the articles and posts regarding lightweight migration and it makes sense. The only question I had is, do I have to do anything before I ship the app?

My understanding is, after I release, if I want to change anything in the model, I set up a second model object with the NSMigratePersistentSToreAutomaticallyOptio and NSInferMappingModelAUtomatiallyOption in the App Delegate.

Do I have to do anything else before I release the first version of my app?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a second version of the object model (i.e. the Core Data graph, which you do in Xcode rather than in code) if you want to make any modifications, and set up your persistent store object using the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312137/871586). Provided that you aren't making very complex changes to the data model or moving to a new model this will usually just work.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. That is helpful and just to confirm, there is nothing I need to do *before* the first version of my app releases is there (to prepare for future migrations, etc). This first version of course only has the one data model version so far but just wanted to confirm nothing to be done before releasing v1.

Comment: No, you will not need to do anything with the first version of the app, because you will be using the first version of the object graph. The two persistent store properties don't affect how the Core Data files are setup, just how they are dealt with *if* a migration is required.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - absolutely perfect