# Change entity and update app

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a app in app store, but now I added new attribute to entity. How can I update user's entity without deleting app and lose data?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementation of "Automatic Lightweight Migration" for Core Data (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone)

Comment: Make sure you do so in a new version of the datastore and a new version of the the app.  iOS should handle the migration.

Comment: I added new version i update storeURL but my core data is empty. Do you have any examples of migration datas?

Answer (score 1):

1) Click on your xcdatamodel file in Xcode 
2) Choose the menu Editor in the upper bar 
3) Click on Add version model 
4) Create a new model based on the previous one 
5) Perform your updates in the new created xcdatamodel file

The app will automatic handle your updates

Comment: Yes but I wanna migration data I used lightweight migration I write function but can you help me with it? storeURL it is new version or old? http://pastebin.com/fDymKbX9

Comment: The steps I wrote are for data migration. When adding a new xcdatamodel version, the sdk will handle the old data and get it to the new model, which has more columnds and etc.

Comment: I dont understand I done everything. But when I run app again with new version it show me only error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`