# Where to add `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` in Swift Core Data Application?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swift2, core-data-migration

I created a new Swift application from the Core Data document based template. The application is working fine, but for a new version I would like to add **lightweight migration**.

In the core data documentation I read, that I just have to add some options to in the `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` method, but where is actually no hint **where** this method is called/added.

I have the `Document` class which is derived from `NSPersistentDocument` and also the application delegate.

- What do I have to add to the project for lightweight migration?
- **Where is the method `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` called?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (hidden) in the documentation of `NSPersistentDocument`.

> You can customize the architecture of the persistence stack by overriding the methods NSPersistentDocument and configurePersistentStoreCoordinator(for:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:). You might wish to do this, for example, to specify a particular managed object model.

Override `func configurePersistentStoreCoordinator(for url: URL, ofType fileType: String, modelConfiguration configuration: String?, storeOptions: [String : AnyObject]? = [:])`. Add your options to `storeOptions` and call super.

Answer (score 0):

see [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW4)

in Swift create options and call addPersistentStoreWithType

```
let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true]
try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options)
```

this is done in `lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`  in `appDelegate:(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`

**Edit says:** This is for iOS apps only, for document based apps you'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770959/core-data-light-migration-on-os-x)

Comment: From where did you get the variable `coodinator`?

Comment: have a look at the core data template app, it's all there ;)
`let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)`

Comment: The question is about the "Core Data **document based** template"

Comment: Ah, well, my fault. Then your question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770959/core-data-light-migration-on-os-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770959/core-data-light-migration-on-os-x) and Willeke's answer is correct