# Core Data Lightweight Migration in a Document Based OSX application Swift 4

Tags: macos, core-data

Interesting problem...

I'm creating a Document based app and now need to convert my CoreData model so that it will use lightweight migration.

I've added a new model version and set it up as needed, and also selected v2 of my model as the current. Now I need to set up lightweight migration. I've done this before in another app, but in my previous app it wasn't a document based app (and it was also using an older version of Xcode.)

The problem I have now is: I did not set up the persistent store in this application, and thus there is no code in any of my files to persistent store... so I have no idea how or where to add the options dictionary so that lightweight migration will work.

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never done it, but does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimanageddocument/1622666-persistentstoreoptions) help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's the options dictionary I was referring to in my question.  The issue is I have no idea how to pass it to the Persistent Store because I didn't create the Persistent Store.

The last time I did this, I coded the setup of the Persistent Store but I didn't this time because, and I'm making an assumption here, XCODE sets it up automatically when you are creating a Document based application.

Comment: The link I provided is to a property of the UIManagedDocument - can't you set that property before opening the document, and it will then pass it to the persistent store coordinator?

Comment: Isn't UIManagedDocument iOS?  This is in an OS X Application.

Comment: Update: the piece of the puzzle I was missing is that I had to Override the configurePersistentStoreCoordinator.  Doh!

Comment: Sorry, I must read Tags more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

[Core Data light migration on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770959/core-data-light-migration-on-os-x)

I just needed to override the function with my own version in my Document.swift file.  Tested and working.