# Swift 4 in Xcode 9 - How to lightweight Core Data migration？

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift4, ios11

My Core Data will update one more attribute and , to avoid crashing , I added a new model version as first, and furthermore:

The most of the keys about this issue is that change :

```
coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
```

options: nil  in the code  to

```
options:[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
```

But In my *appdelegate.swift* , I can’t find any *“persistentStoreCoordinator”*, so can I migrate CoreData in my version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
You can achieve like this:

let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YourDbModelName")
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription() 
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true 
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true 
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don’t know that migrate automatically.

Comment: @CLOX I  tried your answer, but I still get the same error, I'm using Objective C

Answer (score 5):

The solution from Gulshan Kumar is good. In my case, it didn't work because the container already had one description object, and setting

```
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

effectively deleted that object, with the result that the model did not load. I used

```
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(description)
```